# python urllib2 - reading a page after all scripts ran

Tags: python, html, urllib2

I am trying to read a page with urllib2, in order to extract data from the page. Part of the page is generated per load, and when I am reading the url with urllib2 this part is not in the html I am getting.

The url is http://nametrends.net/name.php?name=Ruby , and I am trying to get the table that is generated for the graph. 
For example:

```
<div aria-label="A tabular representation of the data in the chart." style="position: absolute; left: -10000px; top: auto; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden;">
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <tr><td>Sat Feb 01 1947 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)</td><td>0.048</td><td>0</td></tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
</div>
```

My current code is:

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
req = urllib2.Request('http://nametrends.net/name.php?name=Ruby')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

html = BeautifulSoup(the_page)
print "tabular" in html
for table in html.find_all('table'):
    print 1
```

it does not find that table , and there is no div in the html with the text tabular (which is the label of the div that contains the table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The table is filled with the data returned by the additional XHR request to `getfrequencyjson.php` endpoint. You need to make that request in your code and parse the JSON data:

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.99 Safari/537.36'}

with requests.Session() as session:
    session.headers = headers
    session.get('http://nametrends.net/name.php', params={'name': 'ruby'}, headers=headers)

    response = session.get('http://nametrends.net/chartdata/getfrequencyjson.php', params={'name': 'ruby'})
    results = response.json()
    print results
```

Comment: seem like we're quite in line answering the same question ;)

Comment: @Anzel yup, we need to adjust our schedules :)

Comment: This seems a bit less of an overhead (as opposed to opening a browser), but the data comes in a weird format  :)

Comment: @alecxe, how did you find the  appropriate php method?

Comment: @Quantico Just used browser developer tools (Network tab). Yeah, I realize that this approach is a low-level bare metal one, as opposed to high-level selenium option. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If alternative other than **urllib2** is possible, **Selenium** can perform this kind of task with ease, with actual browser simulation:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://nametrends.net/name.php?name=Ruby'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)
# wait until 'tabular' appears on browser
assert 'tabular' not in driver.page_source

html = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
for table in html.find_all('table'):
    print table
```

Comment: I will give it a try, and report back

Comment: working. I picked the other answer because it had less overhead.

Comment: @Quantico, sure I'm happy with it. And yes alecxe answer is very solid and you can learn about the reason of **WHY** the element isn't in the page at the first place. Thorough understanding of how HTML works with definitely benefits you in future :)

Answer (score 0):

At the start I would go:

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(the_page)
html = bs.html
```

Your code doesn't look to bad. going...

```
print str(BeautifulSoup(the_page))
```

will show what Beautiful soup parsed the page into.

Comment: The issue with beautifulSoup was that it did not have access to data that was generated from the script